# I want to create a base Windows service in c# and inherit other services from it

Tags: c#, windows, inheritance, service

Is it possible to create a base Windows service and inherit from it? I have searched for a while now and cannot find any info.

I have a base windows service class with some basic functionality. I then inherit from the base class and override the OnStart, OnStop...methods.

When I install the inherited service, it starts, and then stops with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're after.  You should look into Dependency Injection.  If I "read" you right, that's the concept you're trying to pursue.

Also, look into Inversion of Control.  I think you're after Dependency Injection, but it's important to understand both concepts discreetly:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/592372/Dependency-Injection-DI-vs-Inversion-of-Control-IO

Some say they're different.  Some say DI is a subset of IoC.  Semantics aside, I think this is your ticket.

Comment: i have used DI and IOC before, but not sure how that would help. I want to put some basic functionality in a base windows service class, and then inherit other windows services from it.

Comment: Well, then, I didn't read you right.  Once you build the executable, that's the context you're running in.  IoC seems the right choice to me, but I must not be understanding your scenario.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after starting over, it is working now. Not sure what the issue was.